# The element cannot contain child element because the parent element's content model is text only Error

Tags: column, calculated-column, xml

I want to provision the field using feature.

I have a field which is of type `Calculated` and the `xml` for the column is like below:

```
<Field Type="Calculated"
     ID="{71D763F4-CD20-420D-9E0E-3B8D745B32B8}"
     Name="Select"
     StaticName="Select"
     DisplayName="Select">
<FieldRefs>
  <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
</FieldRefs>    
   <Formula >=CONCATENATE("<div><input type='checkbox' name='chkSelect' id='",[ID],"' /></div>")</Formula>    
</Field>
```

When I deploy the solution an error occurs like:

`Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Feature definition with Id <FeatureID> failed validation, file 'xxx\Elements.xml', line xx, character xx: The element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/:Formula' cannot contain child element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/:input' because the parent element's content model is text only.`

How to tackle this error?

Comment: Hi - I have removed the version tag "2031". I assume that was a refuse and should have been 2013. Anyway, I think that we don't need a version tag here - the problem should have the same solution regardless of the SP version. Fell free to re-add it if you think otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used SharePoint Manager to check the resulting xml schema of a calculated field in one of my developing machine and compare it to yours.

I can report that in my case the formula escapes the "<" and ">" characters as "&lt" and "&gt".

Try something like this:

```
<Field Type="Calculated"
    ID="{71D763F4-CD20-420D-9E0E-3B8D745B32B8}"
    Name="Select"
    StaticName="Select"
    DisplayName="Select">
  <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
  </FieldRefs>    
  <Formula >=CONCATENATE("&ltdiv&gt&ltinput type='checkbox' name='chkSelect' id='",[ID],"' /&gt&lt/div&gt")</Formula>    
</Field>
```

(Note: based on your specific situation you may need to escape also other special characters like ampersand and such).

If anything else fails an alternative can be creating the field directly on SharePoint (you shouldn't need to escape the characters that way) and then copy the schema he generates (as said before, you can see it if you use SharePoint Manager)

Comment: Problem solved? good to know ^_^. I assumed it was something related to the xml parser exploding on that div tag the second I read that error message - I was unsure if the caml declaration used a CData block or some other escape char thoug. I am glad you solved your problem.